# "Easy" Headless File Transfer

Tags: wifi, headless, android, data-transfer, file-sharing

So what I am trying to do is, by any means, transfer one .txt file from my phone to the Raspberry Pi.  However, I want to be able to do this without inputting a pin, via bluetooth, that I have to accept with a Raspberry Pi and a Monitor.  At the time of the transfer I will have no internet connection, but a wifi adapter is connected.  I want this process as headless as possible.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I can hook up the raspberry pi to a monitor to setup and the internet, but above is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Apache running in RPi, create an upload form with two buttons: "Select file" and "Upload".

Upload will be done via phone's browser.

It is headless, not sure whether is easy.

Comment: Thank you. What I am looking for is the way to connect without a bluetooth PIN or an alternative method via WiFi.  I eventually want to get to that any phone can connect and send it a file.  I've tried to get a pin mode on bluetooth, but it still requires me to input the pin on the raspberry pi as well as accept the file.  Another way I have tried is creating a common folder via Ad-Hoc, but it either crashed my /etc/network/interfaces file or did not show up on my PC.  I am going to look into Apache for the final setup, thanks again.

Comment: Via WiFi will not ask for pin. Let me know if you need help with the script (mine is with php)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind keeping a folder in sync as opposed to a specific file, bittorent sync can do that, and [here is a link](http://blog.bittorrent.com/2013/05/23/how-i-created-my-own-personal-cloud-using-bittorrent-sync-owncloud-and-raspberry-pi/)

it does NOT need internet (in fact it works better with local connections)

I don't know about it working over bluetooth (should be possible), but it will work just fine over wifi (could setup a hotspot and either have the phone connect to it or have it connect to the phone)

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for.  I have setup a script that will update my WiFi settings based on a text file.  I am looking to just transfer the file without internet, including my data plan's.  Also, this wouldn't work if I changed phones. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Rattlehead300 - I believe it would work even if you changed phones (but you would need to re-enter the secret key on the phone) - as for why it's getting negative posts, I believe you are fighting against the inherent "security" of the BT protocol which requires the pin.. but perhaps it would be better for the down-voters to explain themselves instead.